# Show the result of execution Celery task through API

Tags: python, django, celery

I get several website addresses in turn from POST request. I will get the job ID. The task collects the number of any HTML-tags. Next, through api, y ou need to display the result by the task number. How to implement saving results from tasks?

I will use this code to count HTML-tags:

```
@app.task(serializer='json')
def demo(request, some_url):
    if request.method=="POST" 
        page = requests.get(some_url)
        tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

        all_elms = tree.cssselect('*')
        all_tags = [x.tag for x in all_elms]

        c = Counter(all_tags)
        """for e in c:
            #print('{}: {}'.format(e, c[e]))"""
        return с
```

P.S Code is optional, I have enough links on my topic or ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from celery.result import AsyncResult
from project.celery import app        #import your celery app
res = AsyncResult('task_id', app=app)
res.state #gives you the state of the task
res.get() #gives you the result
```

You can use this snippet in your API

Comment: Can you tell me how to get the task identifier when creating it, so that I can display the identifier for the user? I will be very grateful